# pgadmin4 in docker after restart wtforms.validators.ValidationError: The CSRF session token is missing

Tags: postgresql, windows, docker, pgadmin, pgadmin-4

I have setup postgres + pgadmin4 on docker desktop on windows 10 machine using wsl.

My issue is that afer I restart my pgadmin4 container, I have to relogin to pgadmin4. Otherwise, every attempt at communication yields this in the logss:

```
2023-05-25 10:54:03 ::ffff:172.27.0.1 - - [25/May/2023:07:54:03 +0000] "GET /dashboard/dashboard_stats/1?chart_names=session_stats,tps_stats,ti_stats,to_stats,bio_stats HTTP/1.1" 400 125 "http://localhost:39080/browser/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/113.0.0.0 Safari/537.36 Edg/113.0.1774.50"
2023-05-25 10:54:08 2023-05-25 07:54:08,384: ERROR      pgadmin:        400 Bad Request: The CSRF session token is missing.
2023-05-25 10:54:08 Traceback (most recent call last):
2023-05-25 10:54:08   File "/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/flask_wtf/csrf.py", line 261, in protect
2023-05-25 10:54:08     validate_csrf(self._get_csrf_token())
2023-05-25 10:54:08   File "/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/flask_wtf/csrf.py", line 103, in validate_csrf
2023-05-25 10:54:08     raise ValidationError("The CSRF session token is missing.")
2023-05-25 10:54:08 wtforms.validators.ValidationError: The CSRF session token is missing.
2023-05-25 10:54:08 
2023-05-25 10:54:08 During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
2023-05-25 10:54:08 
2023-05-25 10:54:08 Traceback (most recent call last):
2023-05-25 10:54:08   File "/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1821, in full_dispatch_request
2023-05-25 10:54:08     rv = self.preprocess_request()
2023-05-25 10:54:08   File "/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2313, in preprocess_request
2023-05-25 10:54:08     rv = self.ensure_sync(before_func)()
2023-05-25 10:54:08   File "/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/flask_wtf/csrf.py", line 229, in csrf_protect
2023-05-25 10:54:08     self.protect()
2023-05-25 10:54:08   File "/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/flask_wtf/csrf.py", line 264, in protect
2023-05-25 10:54:08     self._error_response(e.args[0])
2023-05-25 10:54:08   File "/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/flask_wtf/csrf.py", line 307, in _error_response
2023-05-25 10:54:08     raise CSRFError(reason)
2023-05-25 10:54:08 flask_wtf.csrf.CSRFError: 400 Bad Request: The CSRF session token is missing.
```

I have tried every solution I googled and from chatgpt and nothing helped. I've tried adding all sorts of things in the config_local.py file

```
from os import environ

SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE = False
SESSION_COOKIE_HTTPONLY = False
REMEMBER_COOKIE_SECURE = False
REMEMBER_COOKIE_HTTPONLY = False
SESSION_EXPIRATION_TIME = 604800 
CSRF_ENABLED = True
SECRET_KEY = "mysecretkey"
CSRF_SESSION_KEY = "mycookiename"
CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE = False
CSRF_COOKIE_HTTPONLY = False
```

yet nothing helps. if the image is restarted, I have to relogin again.

Is there a way to make sessions persist through logins?

I understand that its written on flask. In my simple flask app, without any extra changes, sessions persist through relogins by default. So it should be possible, right?